# Draw Tree Layout in Java Swing with DefaultMutableTreeNode

Tags: java, swing, layout, tree, jpanel

I would like to draw a hierarchical tree structure from a DefaultMutableTreeNode object that I build previously. I am trying to do it with Java Swing (I don't want to use any external graph library because the drawing is rather simple), but I cannot make it show in a way that it has the root node on the top and all the childern down their respective parent.

I have tried overriding the paintComponent() method in JPanel, but the result doesn't look as hierarchical as [this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/jviewtgo/v8r7/topic/com.ibm.ilog.jviews.diagrammer.doc/Content/Visualization/Documentation/GraphLayout/_media/getstart_Sample1_default.gif).
This is my simple code:

```
        package view;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.util.Enumeration;

    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;

    import model.TreeNode;

    public class GraphicalTreeRenderer extends JPanel {
    TreeNode tree;
    GraphicalPanel graphicalPanel;

    public GraphicalTreeRenderer(GraphicalPanel gr, TreeNode tree2){
        this.tree = tree2;
        this.graphicalPanel = gr;

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    }

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    Enumeration en = this.tree.postorderEnumeration();

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (en.hasMoreElements()) {

      DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) en.nextElement();

      g.fillOval(10 + i * 20,10  + 20 * node.getLevel(), 20, 20);
      g.drawString("" + node.getLevel(), 10 + i * 20, 10 + 20 * node.getLevel());
      i++;

    }


}
```

For now I am just dawing an oval for each node, but I cannot get to position it correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: Any idea on how to position the nodes correctly right down their parents, because with what I've done the root is showing on the right and all the children are showing on the left of each other.